# Java FX combobox not selecting item when there is more than one item

Tags: javafx, combobox

I implemented a code to populate the options in my editable combobox using the value I entered in the combobox, say I type in 'a' the program will search for all products in my database that contains the letter 'a' and then populate the combobox items with those products. See image below:

[image]

However it doesn't select the item if I click on it. Say I click on Ice Cream it won't select the value, my console reports the following error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$177(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Apr 20, 2016 6:36:59 PM com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow addTrailingCells
INFO: index exceeds maxCellCount. Check size calculations for class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin$2$1
```

Java Codes:

```
ComboBox<String> cbox = new ComboBox<>();
        cbox.setPromptText("Make your choice");
        //cbox.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(cbox.getValue()));
        cbox.setEditable(true);
        cbox.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, 
                                            String oldValue, String newValue) {

                products = new ArrayList<Product>();
                Connection conn = dbConnect.openConnection();
                try {
                    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
                    s.execute("SELECT iProdID,sProdName FROM tbl_001_product WHERE sProdName LIKE '%"+newValue+"%'");
                    ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
                    cbox.getItems().clear();
                    while(rs.next()){
                        Product product = new Product(rs.getInt("iProdID"),rs.getString("sProdName"));
                        products.add(product);

                        cbox.getItems().add(product.getProdname());
                    }
                    cbox.show();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Is it possible that the selection of an item triggers the listener event again?

Comment: this seems to be a possibility, I'm not very sure how the ChangeListener works. The error from the console does not tell on which line of code the error occured either

Comment: well you should debug your code to see what exacly happens.